# Convenções de codificação em C++

Tags: c++

Olá, estou aprendendo C++, e estou procurando saber as melhores práticas para a criação de variáveis, funções, classes e etc. Já pesquisei na internet sobre o assunto, porém não achei nada que falasse diretamente sobre, ou quando falava era um assunto de certo ponto antigo, que, provavelmente estava obsoleto (creio eu), no entanto fui ler códigos em C++ para tentar entender como é o estilo da linguagem, porém percebi que isto é muito variado, como por exemplo a variável `int windows_size` também pode ser escrita como `int windowsSize`, ou a função `int get_windows_size()` (o uso excessivo do "_" para dar "espaço" me faz pensar que esse estilo de programação vem do C) ser escrita como `int GetWindowsSize()` ou até `int getWindowsSize()` e isso aumentou ainda mais a minha incerteza sobre como programar (ou tentar) dentro dos padrões da linguagem, por isso venho aqui perguntar qual o padrão correto de codificação do C++, desde já, agradeço a todos que responderem

Comment: Depende de quem programa, a biblioteca padrão tende seguir snake_case.

Comment: Eu vejo muito o snake_case em vários códigos, acredito que seja o mais adotado pelos programadores de C++

Comment: Andei pesquisando em inglês e achei um documento da Google que diz o estilo de código que ela usa em seus projetos, acredito que irei seguir o estilo também, achei muito útil e conciso na minha opinião, o link dele é este: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o **CamelCase** do Java.

Comment: Se existisse um padrão, ferramentas como clang-tidy seriam obsoletas. O ideal é ser constante, as regras em si não são importantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não acho que tenha algum padrão estritamente definido para C++, mas como apontado pelo Maniero em comentário à sua pergunta, a biblioteca padrão tende a seguir snake_case, e mesmo se houver, várias bibliotecas e frameworks adotam padrões diferentes o que pode acabar misturando-os no seu projeto.

Se você está trabalhando num projeto para alguma organização, é muito benéfico que todos os envolvidos sigam o padrão definido para aquele projeto em específico, para manter a legibilidade e coesão.

Agora, se você está trabalhando em um projeto pessoal, isso fica à sua escolha, como apontado pelo Adriano Siqueira também em comentário à sua pergunta, pode ser uma questão de gosto.

A adoção de um **style guide** (como acontece com projetos feitos em Angular, também da Google) predefinido como você mesmo mencionou também pode ser de grande ajuda.

Embora não seja um style guide, [estas são as melhores diretrizes de codificação C++](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) que você pode seguir, já que elas foram elaboradas (também) pelo próprio criador da linguagem e mostram como produzir código conformante com os últimos padrões lançados como C++11, C++14, C++17, o atual C++20 e o futuro C++23.

Comment: Logo depois que eu encontrei o style guide do Google nas minhas pesquisas, eu encontrei o do próprio criador da linguagem, e realmente os dois ajudam a manter a coesão do código, tentarei seguir um pouco dos dois, pois são ótimos guias, de qualquer forma, obrigado